# How to automatically start Rescuetime on startup (tried crontab and rc.local)

Tags: cron, startup, rc

I have installed rescuetime on debian 9.  It requires the command rescuetime to be run in a terminal, this just keeps running rather than running and closing (it adds an icon into the tray at the bottom left of the screen).  I'm having some difficulty getting this to run on startup.

I have tried crontab and added `@reboot rescuetime`

Also I've tried adding an rc.local file

```
#!/bin/sh -e

sh 'rescuetime.sh'
exit 0
```

rescuetime.sh

```
#!/bin/sh<CR>
rescuetime
```

Neither of these options work.

How do I get rescuetime to run on startup.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the commandline to 'startup applications'.
This worked for me (at least on Ubuntu 18.04).

Comment: Specifically, add `/usr/bin/rescuetime` to the Command input.

Comment: Do you have a sample?